# MAMP: MySQL doesn't start (Cannot open Windows EventLog)

Tags: mysql, windows-10, mamp

When I start MAMP on my Windows 10 it can't start MySQL. Yesterday MAMP could start  the database server but not today.

[image: MAMP desktop]

I have open the mySQL log (*C:\MAMP\logs\mysql_error_log.err*) to see what is happening and I see this:

```
2019-03-03T12:37:02.179451Z 0 [Note] --secure-file-priv is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled
2019-03-03T12:37:02.180417Z 0 [ERROR] Cannot open Windows EventLog; check privileges, or start server with --log_syslog=0
2019-03-03T12:37:02.180436Z 0 [Note] C:\MAMP\\bin\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.24-log) starting as process 4580 ...
```

I have been searching for the EventLog error but I couldn't find something to resolve the problem. What can I do?

Answer (score 5):

Stop all MAMP services.

C:\MAMP\db\mysql\

First backup all files that begin with mysql-bin.* Then delete all files that begin with mysql-bin.* (including mysql-bin.index file.) and start services.

bye